# wstring.find_last_not_of() treats everything after international char as space?

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  wstring my_str(L"El Niño     ");
  cout << my_str.find_last_not_of(L' ');
}
```

This code returns 6 but shouldn't return 7 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indices are zero-based.  The index of the last non-space character is at index 6:

```
L"El Niño     "
        ^
  0123456
```

Comment: Ups, sorry. Ok, I forgot that.